# Stop preview builds versions of insider option

Tags: windows-10

I'm a bit confused about an option in Windows Insiders Program. I'm suscribed to the Slow ring.
Apparently, this is the last build for Slow ring and probably this will be the version which will go to release preview:

[image: Flight Hub]

After that, I guess the production version will be the release in May 28. I would like to stay in that because it will be a more stable version, however **i don't know what to do to get that release or if I already have it.** 
Also, **I don't know if I will be unsuscribed from Slow ring automatically after getting May 2020 release** (which I would prefer also).
There is an option but I'm not sure what it does mean (sorry, I have a localized version) "Stop getting preview builds versions" (my translation) that I have currently disabled:
[image: stop preview versions]

Should I enabled it?

Edit: I forgot to say that the current build installed is the 19041.208

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.  In order to answer your question, your question must be in English (which includes screenshots), and you must indicate what build number you are currently on.

Answer (score 1):

One of the requirements of being a Windows Insider is to accept the builds as they come. Further to add your voice of what you like, do not like, works, does not work.

If you do not want this, go to Start, Settings, Updates and unsubscribe from the program. That is only way to stop the previews.

You can also enable the option at the bottom if you wish to remain as an Insider. I have one machine on this program

Comment: Once you unsubscribe your computer stays at its current build version until the main release catches up to you, and then you'll get regular public releases.

Answer (score 1):

> After that, I guess the production version will be released in May 28. I would like to stay in that because it will be a more stable version, however, I don't know what to do to get that release or if I already have it.

In order to stop receiving Insider Preview builds three things must happen.  You must already be on the Release Preview channel.  This allows you to only receive builds that are being considered for future feature releases.

The 2nd thing that must happen is you must indicate you no longer wish to receive Insider Preview releases.  If you were on the slow or fast channel this wouldn't happen right away.  Since you are already on the most current build what should become Windows 10 version 2004 this will happen almost immediately.

The third thing that must happen is the feature release must be formally released.

> Should I enabled it?

Yes;  however, until the next feature release is actually released, it will still indicate you are still receiving Insider Preview builds.